# I have an Excel Template And I have Edit It from c# Save new File

Tags: c#, excel

Hey guys I have template of excel Which is given by Client  I want to set values in it and save new file Please tell me how to do it

Comment: So you want to automate Excel. There are several good online resources for this, [like this one from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/302084).

Comment: I'm doing this by Console app but i'm having problem in asp.net

Comment: If it's a Console app, why are you using ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use Interop. I use OpenXML to build workbooks from scratch, but it has a steep learning curve. Interop is well described here in StackOverflow and Microsoft has helpful doco. Do some research and come back with specific questions.